# Convert Dates from a Data Frame from Numeric into Date Format in R (produces NAs)

Tags: r, date, format

I'm a Rookie with R. I have read in a Data Frame from Excel in R with the read.csv2 call, (Converted the Excel-file into csv).
I changed every Date in the table to a Y-M-D Format and wanted to use:

```
lapply(df$dates, as.Date, Format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

but it produces NAs for every Date then.
When i ask for the mode it says the Dates are "numeric".
I tried to convert into character before into Dates with:

```
lapply(df$dates, as.character)
```

I dont know why it producs the NAs. Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide some sample from your data

Comment: May be difficult. Its data from a company. I know that makes it more difficult.

Comment: You can create some reproducible example.

Comment: doing it right now

Comment: dont wanna sound stupid, but where can i upload my sample?

Comment: Just copy and paste the result of `dput(df$dates)`.

Comment: try `as.Date(df$dates, origin = "1899-12-30")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the pain of finding the good format, there is `dataPreparation` package which provide a function to do that easily.

```
require(dataPreparation)
df <- setColAsDate(df, cols = "dates")
```

It will try to guess the format among thousand of various formats.

(NB: Please note that I'm the developer of this package.)